# sed/awk edit one line

Tags: regex, sed

I have to edit a line in place in a jad file.

`MIDlet-Version: 0.5.38` should become `MIDlet-Version: 0538`

I'm having trouble finding the line in the file.
If I had the line already, I'd do:

```
echo 'MIDlet-Version: 0.5.38' | sed s/\\.//g
```

I tried several variations of:

```
sed -i 's/\(MIDlet-Version: \)\\.//replace/g' myfile.jad
```

can somebody tell me what's wrong and how to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
sed -i '/MIDlet-Version: /{s/\.//g}' file.jad
```

This will remove all the periods from `file.jad` **only** on lines containing `MIDlet-Version:` and store the changes back to `file.jad`.